# How to use @Binding optional on TextField utilizing CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I have a CoreData entity called `Counter`, and I am wanting to make a view where the user has the ability to change some of the values. An element of the entity is sent to the `EditCounterView` inside the `counter` Binding variable. I want the user to able to edit the title of the element. However, I am having trouble trying to get the TextField binding to work properly. I get these two errors:

`Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<String?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'`

`Value of optional type 'FetchedResults<Counter>.Element?' (aka 'Optional<Counter>') must be unwrapped to refer to member 'title' of wrapped base type 'FetchedResults<Counter>.Element' (aka 'Counter')`

With regards to the first error, I have no idea how I can fix this issue, as I have been trying to figure it out for a while. With regards to the second error, it suggests I either force unwrap or chain the optional. But when I do this, it gives me another error telling me to remove this.

My code is below:

```
struct EditCounterView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @Binding var editingCounter: Bool
    @Binding var counter: FetchedResults<Counter>.Element?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                CounterCellView(title: counter!.title!, icon: counter!.icon!, color: counter!.color!, date: counter!.date!)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 80)
                    .padding()
                Form {
                    Section {
                        TextField("Required", text: $counter.title) // Where I am getting the error.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reread your question. Here is my corrected answer. I changed your view a bit. I changed how `counter` was passed in to a simple `let`. Managed objects are classes conform to `ObservableObject`. You can pass them in as constants and still update their values.

I then took that value and made a custom binding that will take the value and then update the value. It is written presuming that `counter.title` is optional, but that `counter` itself is not.

```
struct EditCounterView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @Binding var editingCounter: Bool
    let counter: Counter

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                CounterCellView(title: counter.title!, icon: counter.icon!, color: counter.color!, date: counter!.date!)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 80)
                    .padding()
                Form {
                    Section {
                        // Custom Binding here...
                        TextField("Required", text: Binding<String>(
                            get: { counter.title ?? "" },
                            set: { newValue in
                                item.title = newValue
                            })
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get the second error after trying out your suggestions.

Comment: That is because counter is optional. You would have to force unwrap it using `!` or optionally unwrap it with a default value. SwiftUI requires optionals to somehow be unwrapped, because the value could be null.